# Elastic Search / Logstash run command after import

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, import, logstash

I'm using logstash (with jdbc-input) to import documents from DB (MariaDB) to Elastic Search, sheduled every 5 minutes.
The duration of that run depends on the number of docuemnts added since the last run in the db.

Is there a way to fire an event or an command, if the import of an set of documents in Elastic Search is done?

I need to work with the documents as fast as possible after they are stored in Elastic Search.

Comment: You could maybe leverage the [`exec`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-exec.html) output plugin to execute a command if a condition is satisfied.

Comment: @Val Is there a condition I could check at this point, if import is finished? Without condition the exec output plugin would execute at the same time where the import to elasticsearch starts, right?

Comment: If you have sequential IDs and you know when the last one is reached, you could use that. Otherwise, you could also execute a shell script that checks if Logstash is running and exits immediately if it's the case.